# How do I output latest distinct values of specific fields and all other colums?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I need a query which will return all latest entries for specific distinct value of a fields.
Example I have table with with 2 columns: `ComputerName`, `date`.
I want to return all distinct values for `ComputerName` and latest `date` for each of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only need the maximum `date` per computer:

```
table
| summarize max(date) by ComputerName
```

alternatively, if you need the entire records with latest `date` per computer:

```
table
| summarize arg_max(date, *) by ComputerName
```

Relevant docs:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/summarizeoperator
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/max-aggfunction
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction